# Console is throwing Unterminated JSX contents error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to set up a basic react example using jspm/systemjs and babel. I have this code here to show a simple page and am getting an error

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
displayName: 'MainComponent',
propTypes: {
    item: React.PropTypes.object
},
render: function render() {
    return (
        <div class="builder-conteiner">

        <div>;
    );
}
});

React.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Nothing is showing up, the console is throwing "Unterminated JSX contents", and babel is pointing to the `react.render` line:

```
 17 | React.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById('app'))
    |                               ^
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have 2 unclosed `<div>` tags in your `render()` and a semicolon that probably doesn't belong. I'd get rid of those (e.g. close them, delete the semicolon in `<div>;` if it doesn't belong) and try it again.

Comment: also `class` should be `className`

Comment: also ``builder-conteiner`` [sic] is misspelled.

Comment: Also happens when any element has unclosed tags not just for divs.

Answer (score 0):

Give / in closing div element and remove semicolon(;) after div element.

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
displayName: 'MainComponent',
propTypes: {
    item: React.PropTypes.object
},
render: function render() {
    return (
        <div class="builder-conteiner">

        </div>
    );
}
});

React.render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```